# Laravel attributes for Categories What is the best way?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, package

I have a table for the categories which is:

```
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->longText('title');
    $table->integer('parent_id')->default(0);
    $table->unique(array('slug'));
    $table->timestamps();
```

and i have for Products :

```
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->longText('title');
            $table->string('price')->nullable();
            $table->longText('address')->nullable();
            $table->longText('excerpt')->nullable();
            $table->longText('content')->nullable();
            $table->text('seller_phone')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
```

**I want to add attributes for each product
But according to its category**

**An example I have two categories:**

**The first real estate**

**The second cars**

**When adding a product in the real estate department, I want it to have different characteristics from the automotive division**

**I looked for Pakage to help me in the matter and did not find any package that had died. Is there any idea for help?**

Comment: What is the meaning of that `I want it to have different characteristics from the automotive division`

Comment: The car category will have the product, for example, color and model year,

Comment: The real estate category will be the product, for example, the number of rooms and the age of construction